# C# Custom CheckBox + Custom Binding Data Type

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created my own checkbox (UserControl). It has a property called ControlSource which works as the binding source. However, the Data Type of ControlSource is also a custom type. After playing around,

```
    ...
    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true), Browsable(true), Category("Behavior")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public IMyBool ControlSource
    {
        get { return this.chx.Checked ? IMyBool.True : IMyBool.False; }
        set { this.chx.Checked = value.Value; }
    }
    ...
```

I tried an interface solution here:

```
   public interface IMyBool
{
    bool Value { get; set; }

    IMyBool True { get; }
    IMyBool False { get; }
}

public class MyBool
{
    protected bool? _bValue = null;

    protected string _sTrue = String.Empty;
    protected string _sFalse = String.Empty;
    protected string _sNull = String.Empty;

    public MyBool(bool? bValue = null)
    {
        this._bValue = bValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._bValue.HasValue ? (this._bValue.Value ? _sTrue : _sFalse) : _sNull;
    }

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return this._bValue.Value; }
        set { this._bValue = value; }
    }
}

public class MyInvoiceBool : MyBool, IMyBool
{
    public static implicit operator MyInvoiceBool(bool? bValue)
    {
        return bValue.HasValue ? (bValue.Value ? True : False) : Null;
    }
    public static implicit operator bool?(MyInvoiceBool ivbValue)
    {
        return ivbValue._bValue;
    }

    public MyInvoiceBool(bool? bValue = null)
    {
        base._sTrue = "Rechnung wird gestellt";
        base._sFalse = "Rechnung wird nicht gestellt";
        base._bValue = bValue;
    }

    public static MyInvoiceBool True
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceBool(true); }
    }
    public static MyInvoiceBool False
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceBool(false); }
    }
    public static MyInvoiceBool Null
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceBool(); }
    }
}

public class MyInvoiceAddressBool : MyBool
{
    public static implicit operator MyInvoiceAddressBool(bool? bValue)
    {
        return bValue.HasValue ? (bValue.Value ? True : False) : Null;
    }
    public static implicit operator bool?(MyInvoiceAddressBool ivbValue)
    {
        return ivbValue._bValue;
    }

    public MyInvoiceAddressBool(bool? bValue = null)
    {
        base._sTrue = "Abweichende Rechnungsadresse";
        base._bValue = bValue;
    }

    public static MyInvoiceAddressBool True
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceAddressBool(true); }
    }
    public static MyInvoiceAddressBool False
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceAddressBool(false); }
    }
    public static MyInvoiceAddressBool Null
    {
        get { return new MyInvoiceAddressBool(); }
    }
}
```

My aim is that I can use my own bool data type which knows an alternative string expression for true, false or null. However, the groupbox control should be coded generally. That's why an interface solution came into my mind. However, it does not work. I am pretty sure that there is a "often used" solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I chose a work around: I inherited the checkbox and explicitly used my custom data type for the control source property. Thus, I do not need an interface or abstract class... Its not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extending the data type, what about implementing an IValueConverter to generate the string representation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx